# In a stored procedure (SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2) is it possible to return a NewSequentialID() without a temp table variable?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, temp-tables, newsequentialid

In a stored procedure (using SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2) is it possible to return a `NewSequentialID()` without a temp table variable?

I can successfully obtain the `NewSequentialID()` by using a temp table:

[Getting Value of NEWSEQUENTIALID() on Insert](http://brian.dobberteen.com/code/getting-value-of-newsequentialid-on-insert/)

Perhaps I’m old school, but I try to refrain from using temp tables unless absolutely necessary… though this might be a case where it is absolutely necessary…

IF I try:

```
DECLARE @NewSequentialID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
SET @NewSequentialID = NEWID()
```

… it works as expected.

IF I try:

```
DECLARE @NewSequentialID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
SET @NewSequentialID = NEWSEQUENTIALID()
```

… I receive the following error:

> *The newsequentialid() built-in function can only be used in a DEFAULT
>   expression for a column of type ‘uniqueidentifier’ in a CREATE TABLE
>   or ALTER TABLE statement. It cannot be combined with other operators
>   to form a complex scalar expression.*

- Is the ONLY solution to use a temp table method?
- Does anyone know of a reason why Microsoft implemented a difference between `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` to work like `NEWID()`?
- Anyone know if there's a chance Microsoft will update `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` to work like `NEWID()`?

Geo

UPDATE --
I'm not sure why Microsoft choose to implement the method in this manner, since they state that, "NEWSEQUENTIALID is a wrapper over the Windows UuidCreateSequential function"... but it appears that there is no non-temp-variable table method. (At least as of yet.)
Thanks for everyone's comments / answers. [Moderator Note:] I'm not sure what to do with a question when the answer is "not possible". So I'm going to give @marc_s credit for detailing a workaround.

Comment: The answer is "no".  Can you explain what you are trying to do?  Perhaps there is a better solution.

Comment: I need to return the guid created by the new record in the sproc to the calling program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now - `newsequentialid()` can **only** be used as a default constraint on a column. That's what the error message pretty clearly says, too.

So in order to get your sequential GUID's - you must have a table. No other way to do this. And no other way in SQL Server 2012, either.

I have no idea nor any information as to why there's such a difference, and why Microsoft chose to implement it this way....

**Update:**

OK, so you need to get that value that is being inserted into your table - how about using the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)?

Something like:

```
DECLARE @NewIDs TABLE (NewSeqID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(list-of-columns)
OUTPUT INSERTED.NewSeqID INTO @NewIDs(NewSeqID)
VALUES (.........)
```

This way, the output from the `INSERT` operation - the newly created sequential GUIDs - is being stored into that table variable, and you can use that, return it, slice it - whatever you like!

Comment: newsequentialid() is used in the table definition for the DEFAULT value of the column.  I need to return the guid created by the new record in the sproc to the calling program.

Answer (score 1):

the official Microsoft saying is:

> NEWSEQUENTIALID() can only be used with DEFAULT constraints on table
>   columns of type uniqueidentifier. For example: CREATE TABLE myTable
>   (ColumnA uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID())

described here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx

NewID generates a random number and the other is the next sequential number.